# Error when trying to join tables mySQL

Tags: mysql, join, distinct

I am completely new to mySQL so please bear with me. When I try to get distinct columns from the following tables, Redshifts, FOF, FOFMtree I get this error

**EDIT** The website that stores the data uses PaQu to query

```
Unknown column 'r.r.' in 'field list'
```

What I only want rows where entries match and to do this I am using the query below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.*, mt.*, f.* FROM MDR1.FOFMtree mt, MDR1.FOF f, MDR1.Redshifts r 
WHERE mt.fofId = f.fofId AND f.mass = mt.mass AND f.snapnum=r.snapnum
```

The query plan is below

```
-- The query plan used to run this query: 
--------------------------------------------------
-- CALL paquExec('SELECT DISTINCT `r`.`snapnum` AS `r__snapnum`,`r`.`aexp` AS `r__aexp`,`r`.`zred` AS `r__zred` FROM MDR1.Redshifts AS `r` ', 'aggregation_tmp_42723925')
-- CALL paquExec('SELECT `f`.`fofId` AS `f__fofId`,`f`.`snapnum` AS `f__snapnum`,`f`.`level` AS `f__level`,`f`.`NInFile` AS `f__NInFile`,`f`.`x` AS `f__x`,`f`.`y` AS `f__y`,`f`.`z` AS `f__z`,`f`.`vx` AS `f__vx`,`f`.`vy` AS `f__vy`,`f`.`vz` AS `f__vz`,`f`.`np` AS `f__np`,`f`.`mass` AS `f__mass`,`f`.`size` AS `f__size`,`f`.`disp` AS `f__disp`,`f`.`disp_v` AS `f__disp_v`,`f`.`delta` AS `f__delta`,`f`.`spin` AS `f__spin`,`f`.`angMom_x` AS `f__angMom_x`,`f`.`angMom_y` AS `f__angMom_y`,`f`.`angMom_z` AS `f__angMom_z`,`f`.`angMom` AS `f__angMom`,`f`.`axis1` AS `f__axis1`,`f`.`axis2` AS `f__axis2`,`f`.`axis3` AS `f__axis3`,`f`.`axis1_x` AS `f__axis1_x`,`f`.`axis1_y` AS `f__axis1_y`,`f`.`axis1_z` AS `f__axis1_z`,`f`.`axis2_x` AS `f__axis2_x`,`f`.`axis2_y` AS `f__axis2_y`,`f`.`axis2_z` AS `f__axis2_z`,`f`.`axis3_x` AS `f__axis3_x`,`f`.`axis3_y` AS `f__axis3_y`,`f`.`axis3_z` AS `f__axis3_z`,`f`.`ix` AS `f__ix`,`f`.`iy` AS `f__iy`,`f`.`iz` AS `f__iz`,`f`.`phkey` AS `f__phkey`,`r`.`r.` AS ``,`r`.`r__snapnum` AS `r__snapnum`,`r`.`r__aexp` AS `r__aexp`,`r`.`r__zred` AS `r__zred` FROM MDR1.FOF AS `f` JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT `r__snapnum`,`r__aexp`,`r__zred` FROM `aggregation_tmp_42723925` ) AS `r` WHERE ( `f`.`snapnum` = `r`.`r__snapnum` ) ', 'aggregation_tmp_57441076')
-- CALL paquExec('SELECT `mt`.`fofTreeId` AS `mt__fofTreeId`,`mt`.`fofId` AS `mt__fofId`,`mt`.`treeSnapnum` AS `mt__treeSnapnum`,`mt`.`descendantId` AS `mt__descendantId`,`mt`.`lastProgId` AS `mt__lastProgId`,`mt`.`mainLeafId` AS `mt__mainLeafId`,`mt`.`treeRootId` AS `mt__treeRootId`,`mt`.`x` AS `mt__x`,`mt`.`y` AS `mt__y`,`mt`.`z` AS `mt__z`,`mt`.`vx` AS `mt__vx`,`mt`.`vy` AS `mt__vy`,`mt`.`vz` AS `mt__vz`,`mt`.`np` AS `mt__np`,`mt`.`mass` AS `mt__mass`,`mt`.`size` AS `mt__size`,`mt`.`spin` AS `mt__spin`,`mt`.`ix` AS `mt__ix`,`mt`.`iy` AS `mt__iy`,`mt`.`iz` AS `mt__iz`,`mt`.`phkey` AS `mt__phkey`,`f`.`f__fofId` AS `f__fofId`,`f`.`f__snapnum` AS `f__snapnum`,`f`.`f__level` AS `f__level`,`f`.`f__NInFile` AS `f__NInFile`,`f`.`f__x` AS `f__x`,`f`.`f__y` AS `f__y`,`f`.`f__z` AS `f__z`,`f`.`f__vx` AS `f__vx`,`f`.`f__vy` AS `f__vy`,`f`.`f__vz` AS `f__vz`,`f`.`f__np` AS `f__np`,`f`.`f__mass` AS `f__mass`,`f`.`f__size` AS `f__size`,`f`.`f__disp` AS `f__disp`,`f`.`f__disp_v` AS `f__disp_v`,`f`.`f__delta` AS `f__delta`,`f`.`f__spin` AS `f__spin`,`f`.`f__angMom_x` AS `f__angMom_x`,`f`.`f__angMom_y` AS `f__angMom_y`,`f`.`f__angMom_z` AS `f__angMom_z`,`f`.`f__angMom` AS `f__angMom`,`f`.`f__axis1` AS `f__axis1`,`f`.`f__axis2` AS `f__axis2`,`f`.`f__axis3` AS `f__axis3`,`f`.`f__axis1_x` AS `f__axis1_x`,`f`.`f__axis1_y` AS `f__axis1_y`,`f`.`f__axis1_z` AS `f__axis1_z`,`f`.`f__axis2_x` AS `f__axis2_x`,`f`.`f__axis2_y` AS `f__axis2_y`,`f`.`f__axis2_z` AS `f__axis2_z`,`f`.`f__axis3_x` AS `f__axis3_x`,`f`.`f__axis3_y` AS `f__axis3_y`,`f`.`f__axis3_z` AS `f__axis3_z`,`f`.`f__ix` AS `f__ix`,`f`.`f__iy` AS `f__iy`,`f`.`f__iz` AS `f__iz`,`f`.`f__phkey` AS `f__phkey`,`f`.`r__snapnum` AS `r__snapnum`,`f`.`r__aexp` AS `r__aexp`,`f`.`r__zred` AS `r__zred` FROM MDR1.FOFMtree AS `mt` JOIN ( SELECT `f__fofId`,`f__snapnum`,`f__level`,`f__NInFile`,`f__x`,`f__y`,`f__z`,`f__vx`,`f__vy`,`f__vz`,`f__np`,`f__mass`,`f__size`,`f__disp`,`f__disp_v`,`f__delta`,`f__spin`,`f__angMom_x`,`f__angMom_y`,`f__angMom_z`,`f__angMom`,`f__axis1`,`f__axis2`,`f__axis3`,`f__axis1_x`,`f__axis1_y`,`f__axis1_z`,`f__axis2_x`,`f__axis2_y`,`f__axis2_z`,`f__axis3_x`,`f__axis3_y`,`f__axis3_z`,`f__ix`,`f__iy`,`f__iz`,`f__phkey`,``,`r__snapnum`,`r__aexp`,`r__zred` FROM `aggregation_tmp_57441076` ) AS `f` WHERE ( `mt`.`fofId` = `f`.`f__fofId` ) AND ( `f`.`f__mass` = `mt`.`mass` ) ', 'aggregation_tmp_32272878')
-- CALL paquDropTmp('aggregation_tmp_42723925')
-- CALL paquDropTmp('aggregation_tmp_57441076')
-- USE spider_tmp_shard
-- SET @i=0
-- CREATE TABLE cosmosim_user_surfcast23.`2014-10-29-19-33-23-5449` ENGINE=MyISAM SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS `row_id`, `mt__fofTreeId`,`mt__fofId`,`mt__treeSnapnum`,`mt__descendantId`,`mt__lastProgId`,`mt__mainLeafId`,`mt__treeRootId`,`mt__x`,`mt__y`,`mt__z`,`mt__vx`,`mt__vy`,`mt__vz`,`mt__np`,`mt__mass`,`mt__size`,`mt__spin`,`mt__ix`,`mt__iy`,`mt__iz`,`mt__phkey`,`f__fofId`,`f__snapnum`,`f__level`,`f__NInFile`,`f__x`,`f__y`,`f__z`,`f__vx`,`f__vy`,`f__vz`,`f__np`,`f__mass`,`f__size`,`f__disp`,`f__disp_v`,`f__delta`,`f__spin`,`f__angMom_x`,`f__angMom_y`,`f__angMom_z`,`f__angMom`,`f__axis1`,`f__axis2`,`f__axis3`,`f__axis1_x`,`f__axis1_y`,`f__axis1_z`,`f__axis2_x`,`f__axis2_y`,`f__axis2_z`,`f__axis3_x`,`f__axis3_y`,`f__axis3_z`,`f__ix`,`f__iy`,`f__iz`,`f__phkey`,`r__snapnum`,`r__aexp`,`r__zred` FROM `aggregation_tmp_32272878` 
-- CALL paquDropTmp('aggregation_tmp_32272878')
```

What I would like to know is why am I getting this error and how can I avoid it or work around. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you're using [PaQu](https://github.com/adrpar/paqu) which is probably relevant.  This seems to be more of an issue with the PaQu's parser than MySQL.  MySQL wouldn't expand `r.*` to include `\`r\`.\`r.\` AS \`\``

Comment: You are correct. I have edited the question to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with how PaQu is expanding your columns from `r.*` to `r.col1, r.col2, r.col3, ...`

It seems to specifically be having a hard time with your `r` table, `MDR1.Redshifts`.  Somehow the parser is expanding `r.*` to include ``` `r`.`r.` AS `` ``` which is invalid.

Explicitly listing out the columns on the trouble table table should fix the issue.

You might also want to open an [issue with PaQu](https://github.com/adrpar/paqu/issues) and include `DESCRIBE`s of the tables causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting doesn't make sense with what you have posted.  First, try using the more traditional join syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
   FROM MDR1.FOFMtree mt 
           INNER JOIN MDR1.FOF f 
              ON mt.mass=f.mass 
              INNER JOIN MDR1.Redshifts r 
                 ON f.snapnum = r.snapnum;
```

If this doesn't help immediately, try recreating your problem at sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: DRapp thank yo for your reply I will give it a try , but the documentation on the site with the database says               `Table joins
Take care with table joins! These are reformulated again, so check twice here, if the query execution plan has correctly translated your query.
Do NOT use the JOIN keyword exlicitely! This is not supported yet. Use nested queries instead. `

Comment: Tried using your query and got this error `Paqu Error: USING or ON statement: Not yet handled`

Comment: I'm guessing you are using this: https://github.com/adrpar/paqu?  It sounds like it doesn't implement all of the same SQL that MySQL does.  Mr. Llama has it right, above.